# blackberry Playing Ringtone in application

Tags: blackberry

I was wondering if there is a way for a blackberry application to alert the user using the device ringtone.

myrequirement should match like below

1) If the user has the ringtone(phones) set to vibrate, the application will alert the user by   vibrating.
 2) If the user has the ringtone(phones) as Ringtone A, the application will play RingTone A.

is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to use the built in notification profiles. I found the documentation to be a bit confusing so I put together a little example from one of my projects. You can see it [here](http://www.hrbuckley.net/2011/03/08/using-the-blackberry-notifications-manager/). Hope this helps.